# Как скрыть Fragment в android

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Подскажите пожалуйста, как изменить фрагмент чтоб были кнопки skip(при нажатии на которую мы просто войдем в приложение) и hide(при нажатии которого Fragment не будет больше показываться). В файл xml фрагмента добавил эти кнопки и добавил слушателей для кнопок hide и skip но как дальше реализовать?

код MainActivity:

```
package ru.by_em.myfragment;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

FragmentManager fragmentManager;
PreferenceHelper preferenceHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    PreferenceHelper.getInstance().init(getApplicationContext());
    preferenceHelper = PreferenceHelper.getInstance();

    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    runSplash();
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    MenuItem splashItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_splash);
    splashItem.setChecked(preferenceHelper.getBoolean(PreferenceHelper.SPLASH_IS_INVISIBLE));
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_splash) {
        item.setChecked(!item.isChecked());
        preferenceHelper.putBoolean(PreferenceHelper.SPLASH_IS_INVISIBLE, item.isChecked());
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
private void runSplash() {
    if(!preferenceHelper.getBoolean(PreferenceHelper.SPLASH_IS_INVISIBLE)) {
        BlankFragment splashFragment = new BlankFragment();

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.first, splashFragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

}

код activity_main:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

код BlankFragment:

```
        package ru.by_em.myfragment;

    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;

    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


    /**
     * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
     */
    public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

FragmentManager fragmentManager;

public BlankFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    SplashTask splashTask = new SplashTask();
    splashTask.execute();

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, null);

    Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_Skip);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Button_Skip");
            // Create new fragment and transaction



        }
    });

    Button button2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Button_OK");
        }
    });

        return v;
    }



class SplashTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(40);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(getActivity() != null) {
            getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
    }
```

код fragment_blank:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/splashreminder"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Skip"
        android:id="@+id/button_Skip" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OK"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

код PreferenceHelper:

```
    package ru.by_em.myfragment;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;

    /**
         * Created by Admin on 29.11.2015.
     */
    public class PreferenceHelper {

public static final String SPLASH_IS_INVISIBLE = "splash_is_invisible";

private static PreferenceHelper instance;

private Context context;

private SharedPreferences preferences;

private PreferenceHelper() {

}

public static PreferenceHelper getInstance() {
    if (instance ==null) {
        instance = new PreferenceHelper();
    }
    return instance;
}

public void init(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public void putBoolean(String key, boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(key, value);
    editor.apply();
}

public boolean getBoolean(String key) {
    return preferences.getBoolean(key, false);
}
}
```